# Why is Ubuntu not recognizing Windows 10 on my machine?

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, uefi, windows-10, lts

I struggled with the installation until I learned I needed to disable Fast Boot. I had Secure Boot disabled but didn't realize I needed to disable Fast Boot in Windows as well. It kept failing at GRUB installation and gave me a fatal error, until I disabled Fast Boot.

This is not relevant to my question other than each of many times I tried to reinstall Ubuntu, I was never offered the option to install alongside windows because no other operating system was detected.

Windows Boot Manager has a UEFI tag on it which is my primary drive to boot from (C).

I have Windows 10 booting from the Windows Boot Manager and Ubuntu booting from the same drive. I have one 20 GB partition for the installed Ubuntu system (3 partitions: \,  swap, and GRUB) and I have a secondary hard drive that I have partitioned for storage. (When I figure that part out.)

What do I need to do to make Ubuntu recognize my Windows OS so I don't have to go into my BIOS menu and boot manually? Do I need to do something to my Windows system to make it visible to the Ubuntu system? I'm sorry posting this if this was already covered but a lot of suggestions were to run Boot-Repair.

I don't feel like this is an issue with boot. When I select my C drive that is not UEFI, Ubuntu boots fine, and if it were to detect my Windows OS I'd probably get the option for dual boot.

I am also speculating and everything above could be completely wrong because I've only been using this operating system for an hour at best.

My Ubuntu version is 16.04.3 LTS.

Comment: Do you have the option to disable UEFI? And if so, could you try to do it? I am not saying that this will fix your problem, but UEFI is pretty often an issue with linux.

Comment: @Adrijaned No, it is not. UEFI is **seldom** a problem and when there's a problem the cause is a non-standard UEFI implementation for which some workarounds are needed. The problem  here is the opposite actually: Ubuntu was installed in Legacy mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Each of many times I tried to reinstall Ubuntu, I was never offered the option to install Ubuntu alongside Windows because no other operating system was detected. Windows Boot Manager has a UEFI tag on it which is my primary drive to boot from C:. What do I need to do to make Ubuntu recognize my Windows OS so I don't have to go into my BIOS menu and boot manually? Do I need to do something to my Windows system to make it visible to the Ubuntu system?

After a clean reinstall, I got it working. I did in fact install Ubuntu in BIOS mode initially. I found a link suggesting to disable Compatibility Support Module (CSM) when converting Ubuntu from BIOS to UEFI. This may not be relevant in my case since I was reinstalling, but I figured I'd disable it and give it a try.

I performed a clean installation. The first time I installed Ubuntu, I selected to boot from the first DVD drive that appeared on the boot list. This must have been the BIOS version. I overlooked the UEFI bootable DVD drive upon scrolling down further on the list of drives. I booted from the DVD drive that was labeled UEFI this time.

I selected to install alongside Windows successfully, and I can now select which operating system to use at startup.

This seems strange but I went back into BIOS after confirming both Windows and Ubuntu worked and noticed that CSM was enabled. Everything works so I left it like that. Here are screenshots of CSM being enabled in my BIOS for successful booting of both operating systems.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]