# Ubuntu won't see that Windows Ten is Installed On My Solid State Drive

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation

i have a quick question, and when i try to install Ubuntu on my PC it does not see that i have Windows ten installed on my solid state drive., even though i do. I do not want to do the other ways, because i like letting Ubuntu doing it for me. Is there i way i can fix this? I have made a 50 gig space on windows for it to install on. I i have tried other things, but they do not work. I do not know if it is because i have a solid state drive, or if i need to do something in the terminal. I just really want to install Ubuntu alongside windows. Thanks so much.

Comment: while installing you cant see the window10 option,`install alongs side with windows` right ?

Comment: sometime it happened while installing window is not recorginze but after installation grub recoginze that and u have have dua boot in your system . .follow this [tutorial](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1031993/how-to-install-ubuntu-18-04-alongside-windows-10) to  dual boot

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is Ubuntu not recognizing Windows 10 on my machine?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/959481/why-is-ubuntu-not-recognizing-windows-10-on-my-machine)

Comment: Oh? I did not understand at first. I thought you were bragging because you found a way to hide Windows. I've been looking for a HOWTO for years. :) But seriously, if you do manual partitions when installing Ubuntu, don't you notice the windows partitions sitting there? Ubuntu installer has a button about making other OS into boot able option.